# Ad is not visible not refreshing ad

Tags: android, admob

I am facing this strange issue in my current project, although this is not the first time I am integrating it.

Admob is being integrated from within fragment, but I tried from activity too, its not working.

Changing publisher id is not having any effect.

**I have checked other threads for this issue, not of any help.**

Below is the code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>


//======================================
public class AdFragment extends BaseFragment{

    private AdView mAdView;

    //========================
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup vg, Bundle b){
        View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.ads, vg, true);       
        mAdView = (AdView)v.findViewById(R.id.adview);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("ECA025F9DDBA50A6F63387CC3FFF340F").build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        return v;
    }

    //========================
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mAdView.resume();
    }

    //========================
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mAdView.pause();
    }
}
```

Fragment placement:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dip">

    <ListView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ads"
        android:scrollbars="none"></ListView>

    <fragment 
        class="com.paper.AdFragment"
        android:name="com.paper.AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/ads"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is your logcat for the Ads? Also, Try removing the padding in your `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: What does 'its not working' mean? Be explicit. Provide logs.

Comment: The log says this only "Ad is not visible not refreshing ad"

Answer (score 0):

Your ad xml layout is quite redundant. Simply in Ad Fragment write:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup vg, Bundle b){
    mAdView = new AdView(getActivity());
    mAdView.setAdUnitId(getActivity().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id);
    AdRequest adRequest = new   AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("ECA025F9DDBA50A6F63387CC3FFF340F").build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    return mAdView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there was no issue with the code, the problem was the package name.

When we uploaded build on playstore package name was already used by some one else, on changing that in app, it worked.

Hope it helps some one else.
Thanks

Comment: namespaces should be based on web domain names, and hence should never clash.